# In hibernate persisting parent without a nullable child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a situation when using hibernate that my child gets persisted no matter what in a one-to-one mapping.

Say I have a parent entity,

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Parent {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private Child child;

    // getter/setter ...
}
```

Child entity,

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Child {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "child")
    private Parent parent;

    // getter/setter ...
}
```

When saving I always have to,

```
public class ParentServiceImpl ... {
  public void save(ParentDTO parentDTO) {
    // Map parent DTO to parent DAO
    ....
    // Check if child is not null
    if (parentDAO.getChild() != null) {
      childRepository.save(parentDAO.getChild());
    }
  }
}
```

Without having to check with getChild whether child is null or not how can I achieve the persistence in hibernate for a parent with a nullable child ? In order words say I have a parent with no associated child then I want to only create a row for the parent and not a row for the child with nullable columns.

Comment: in that case shouldn't the cascade be on the parent side? - NEvermind, read that wrong

Comment: but you can add: nullable = true to the @JoinColumn

Comment: isnt nullable = true default anyway ?

Comment: yeah you are correct indeed, then I don't understand your question. When saving with a null child it should not create a row with nullable columns and indeed only create the parent row